# Repeat? regex pattern to parse Textus Receptus verse

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to get a solution to this regex problem:

```
import re

letters = "αΑβΒγΓδΔεΕϛϚϜϝζΖηΗθΘιΙυϒYκΚϡϠͲͳλΛωΩμΜτΤνΝξΞοΟσΣϹϲςπΠχΧϙϘϞϟρΡψΨφΦ"
c = '([%s]+) ([^\s]+) ([^\s%s]+)' % (letters, letters)

regex_word_strong_morph = re.compile(c)

verse = "βιβλος G976 G976 N-NSF γενεσεως G1078 N-GSF ιησου G2424 N-GSM χριστου G5547 N-GSM υιου G5207 N-GSM δαβιδ G1138 N-PRI υιου G5207 N-GSM αβρααμ G11 N-PRI"

regex_word_strong_morph.findall(verse)
```

Output:

```
[('βιβλος', 'G976', 'G976'),
 ('γενεσεως', 'G1078', 'N-GSF'),
 ('ιησου', 'G2424', 'N-GSM'),
 ('χριστου', 'G5547', 'N-GSM'),
 ('υιου', 'G5207', 'N-GSM'),
 ('δαβιδ', 'G1138', 'N-PRI'),
 ('υιου', 'G5207', 'N-GSM'),
 ('αβρααμ', 'G11', 'N-PRI')]
```

But first item should be:

```
('βιβλος', 'G976', 'G976', 'N-NSF')
```

And I quess ([^\s]+) should be something like: ([^\s]+){1,2} but it is not quite correct. It is ok to have empty cell on fourth index in case there is only three items matched, for example:

```
('γενεσεως', 'G1078', 'N-GSF', '')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this: (note that I have choosen to put the possible empty field at third position)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re

pattern = u'([Ͱ-ϡ]+) ([A-Z0-9-]+)(?: ([A-Z0-9-]+))? ([A-Z0-9-]+)(?=\\s|$)'

regex_word_strong_morph = re.compile(pattern)

verse = u"βιβλος G976 G976 N-NSF γενεσεως G1078 N-GSF ιησου G2424 N-GSM χριστου G5547 N-GSM υιου G5207 N-GSM δαβιδ G1138 N-PRI υιου G5207 N-GSM αβρααμ G11 N-PRI"

print regex_word_strong_morph.findall(verse)
```

Comment: Seems to work! Where did you get this part: [Ͱ-ϡ]? Is it possible to list/print all characters on that range to double check there are all I need?

Comment: @PHPGAE: Take a look at the unicode table ( http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_des_caract%C3%A8res_Unicode_(0000-0FFF)#Grec_et_copte ) to determine exactly the characters you need (and the range(s)). It is useless to write them one by one.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
>>> import re
>>> c = '([αΑβΒγΓδΔεΕϛϚϜϝζΖηΗθΘιΙυϒYκΚϡϠͲͳλΛωΩμΜτΤνΝξΞοΟσΣϹϲςπΠχΧϙϘϞϟρΡψΨφΦ]+.*?.-.{3})'
>>> regex_word_strong_morph = re.compile(c)
>>> verse = "βιβλος G976 G976 N-NSF γενεσεως G1078 N-GSF ιησου G2424 N-GSM χριστου G5547 N-GSM υιου G5207 N-GSM δαβιδ G1138 N-PRI υιου G5207 N-GSM αβρααμ G11 N-PRI"
```

regex :

```
([αΑβΒγΓδΔεΕϛϚϜϝζΖηΗθΘιΙυϒYκΚϡϠͲͳλΛωΩμΜτΤνΝξΞοΟσΣϹϲςπΠχΧϙϘϞϟρΡψΨφΦ]+.*?.-.{3})
```

demo here : http://regex101.com/r/oL3bX1

Comment: Nice site! However this didn't give me array of strongs and morphology parts ('βιβλος', 'G976', 'G976', 'N-NSF'). True I can now get it with simple split(). Maybe I need to do it in two parts anyway...

Comment: @PHPGAE you can get the result in an array , thats what you wanted right ?

Comment: Yeah, its ok with that kind of array. But with this input, your regex didn't work: εκεινον G1565 D-ASM δει G1163 G5904 V-PQI-3S αυξανειν G837 G5721 V-PAN εμε G1691 P-1AS δε G1161 CONJ ελαττουσθαι G1642 G5745 V-PPN